# Where is the iTunes equivalent for Android?

Tags: samsung, itunes

I have searched this forum with no success for a few days, I apologize if this question has already been answered.  I am a new Android user, switching from an iPhone to a Galaxy Note 3 with Ice Cream.  I have tried using Samsung Kies 3 to replace the features I had with iTunes with no success.   It reports complete syncs, but the information is not complete.  It does not allow the user to manipulate the screens and organize apps the way iTunes allows.  I am looking for software that has all the features of iTunes.  I have found a few that are loaded with ads and very few features.  So far, I have not found any app that allows me to manage apps in terms of updates. Google could have an app that can handle the basic needs of an Android user.  I have not been able to find this.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 7):

You won't find a good "iTunes for Android" for your desktop computer, because Android was designed from the start to eliminate that dependency on a desktop computer. An iPhone uses a protocol that only iTunes understands, so iTunes is the only way to get music and photos onto it (Originally, you had to install apps through iTunes too: there was no App Store on the iPhone itself.)

In contrast, Android phones use MTP to act like any media player device, so they show up as a drive on your desktop computer. (Originally they used the USB mass storage protocol, but that approach had shortcomings.) You can just drag and drop files onto the phone, or you can use a more specific piece of software.

For example, if you want to put music on your phone, and you don't want to drag and drop files, there's a choice of music software that support syncing to non-iPhone music players, including Android phones. Rhythmbox and Clementine are two examples.

Similarly, if you want to put some photos on there, you can just drag-and-drop them if your folders are neatly organised on your desktop computer, or you can use a photo manager like Shotwell or Geeqie.

In your question, you say:

> Google could have an app that can handle the basic needs of an Android user. I have not been able to find this.

and the answer to that is that you've been looking in the wrong place! If you want to organise your home screens and install, update, and remove apps, don't run to your desktop computer: the place to look is on your phone. All that functionality has been on Android phones right from the start, so there's no need for a huge "manage my phone" program on your desktop.

Comment: Dan - good answer, but... Apple and iTunes has stuff scattered everywhere. Its not really possible to sync music, movies, books, etc from a Mac or MacBook to an Android device. You would waste days traversing the file system moving on piece at a time.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes can never be found nor used in Android phones. It is "only" meant for Apple users. Unlike Apple gadgets, Android only can manage the content of their phone via their phone only, there's no trick or there's no app available to do it just like what iTunes does. That makes Apple and Android very different. I used both Apple and Android and the truth is, I love managing Android more than Apple, it's less complicated and I don't have to worry about syncing most of the time.

Samsung Kies only is used for you to sync your phone to a computer, it won't do you anything else. You have a nice phone, Galaxy Note 3, why not try to explore it and maybe you'll realize it's much easier to use than your phone before? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Phone has its default management tool such as Samsung Kies, HTC has Sync manager, but  if you find Samsung Kies crashed from time to time, you can find its alternatives. The free web app [AirMore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airmore) is the iTunes equivalent for Android. Simply use your browser to connect your device and PC.

Comment: Although I made the edit and removed the unnecessary info and the promotion link  the answer still feels a spam.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the your best option would be Wondershare Tunesgo. It costs a little bit of $$$ but it's worth it. I believe they have a free trial version to see if it's a fit for you.